# Using a relative reference (offset) in a COUNTIF function in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having problems using a relative reference (offset) in a COUNTIF function in Excel VBA:

```
buildRef.Offset(i, 2) = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs _
            (range, ">=" & buildRef.Offset(i, 1))
```

This always results in 0 but I know that it's not the correct answer. However,

`WorksheetFunction.CountIfs (range, buildRef.Offset(i, 1))` does give the correct answer.

Can anyone tell me why the **COUNTIFS** function doesn't work when the criteria is "greater than" some relative reference?

Comment: try replacing `buildRef.Offset(i, 1)` with `buildRef.Offset(i, 1)).value`

Comment: what are the address ranges of `buildRef` and `range` ?

Comment: Adding .value still doesn't give me the correct answer.

Comment: range is B2:B1466 and buildRef is C2 on a different sheet

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code. You are getting `0` because of your `i`. The `.Offset(i, 1)` may not be referring to the cell you think it is referring to. I would recommend stepping through the code to check the value of `i`.

Here is an example to show it works. I have hard coded the value of `i` to demonstrate how it works.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range, buildRef As Range

    Set rng = [A1:A10]
    Set buildRef = [D1]

    buildRef.Offset(1, 2) = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=" & buildRef.Offset(1, 1))
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I've checked offset(i,1)'s values. They're correct.

Comment: I just showed you it works. May I see your excel file? If yes then please upload it to a free file sharing site and share the link here. Also if the file and confidential date then replace it with dummy data